MLE of the covariance of the probabilistic PCA (multivariate normal distribution)
To get to the MLE of probalistic PCE, we start with the marginal distribution, which is defined with $x \sim \mathcal N(b, C)$ with $C=WW^\top + \sigma^2 I_d \text{ and } b \in \mathbb{R}^d, W \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times m}$.
The log-likelihood function for the samples $(x_i)_i^{n}$ is now given with
\begin{align*}
\log \mathcal L(\{x_i\} \mid b, W, \sigma^2) = -\frac{nd}{2} \log(2 \pi) - \frac{n}{2} \log|C| - \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - b)^\top C^{-1} (x_i - b)
\end{align*}
The MLE for $b$ is the sample mean $b = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, but my problem is with the covariance.
If you differentiate w.r.t. $W$ you get $\frac{\partial \log \mathcal L}{\partial W} = n(C^{-1} S C^{-1} W - C^{-1} W)$ and if you set it to zero you get the condition $SC^{-1}W = W$.
Now I need to show that $SU = U(\sigma^2 I + D^2)$.
$U D V^\top$ is the singular value decomposition of $W$ with $U \in \mathbb R^{d \times m}$ and $D, V \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ and $D$ diagonal.
There is literature online, but I don't quite understand what is happening:
for example they state that $SUD(D^2+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}V^\top = UDV^\top$ is true.
I understand that they simply plug in the SVD in the condition from the likelihood, but why can they move the matrices like that and also why is the last step in
$WW^\top = UDV^\top V D^\top U^\top = UDD^\top U^\top = D^2$ true?
